# How to apply transition for full height when use bottom:0 and top:0?

Tags: html, css, height, css-transitions

Is there any option apply transition for the css properties without adding `height:100%` ?

Currently the hover works fine as expected but unfortunately there is no transition effect

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

main:hover {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>Hover Me</main>
```

Comment: you cannot transition from auto to a <value> (and viceversa) and look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48973523/css-transition-or-animate-slide-up-from-top100-to-bottom0/48973645#48973645

Comment: Are you ok with a bit of javascript inside?

Comment: @Dekel Looking for pure CSS solution

Answer (score 2):

You need to set initial value to the top:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top:calc(100% - 40px);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

main:hover {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>Hover Me</main>
```

And if you want to keep it dynamic you can try something else.

Here is an idea with flex:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

main {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: auto;
  flex:0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

main:hover {
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<main>Hover Me</main>
```